# Can you capture the Nikon D3000 in Continuous Mode into a PC?

Tags: nikon, tethering, nikon-d3000

The entry level DSLR from Nikon, [D3000](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Digital-SLR/25462/D3000.html#tab-ProductDetail.ProductTabs.TechSpecs), supports a max framerate of 3 FPS in "Continuous mode".

Can you tether the cam to click photos directly into a PC at such a high speed? (Continuous mode?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shooting tethered seems to work very similarly to shooting with an SD card: the camera stores pictures in its internal buffer before transferring them to PC, and therefore can shoot as fast as the buffer can handle. (At least, I haven't noticed any slowness.)

However, don't expect to be able to shoot RAW photos indefinitely at 3 frames per second: your USB connection just won't keep up. I just did a little test with Aperture's tethering, and found that I can sustain a speed of roughly 1 frame per second shooting RAW.